# No Tukey Test on ANOVA package

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to use the ANOVA package and have mathematica display the Tukey PostTest, but all I get is this:

```
ANOVA[Tratamientos, PostTests -> Tukey]

ANOVA::nottest: Tukey is not a valid PostTests entry, and will be ignored. Valid PostTests entries are Bonferroni, Tukey, StudentNewmanKeuls, Duncan, and Dunnett. >>
```

Any advice? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hahaha... _"Tukey is not a valid PostTests entry, and will be ignored. Valid PostTests entries are Bonferroni, **Tukey**, ..."_

Comment: What version are you using? I can't reproduce this back to v.7.

Comment: I'm using version 9, also, I'm on linux.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Win7-64, either v9 or v8. The exact error message is generated if you enter the option value as the string "Tukey" instead of the symbol `Tukey`. Might that have been the case here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work here (Mathematica 8.0):

```
Needs["ANOVA`"]
ANOVA[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 15}, {2, 20}}, PostTests -> Tukey]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 9, so maybe thats the problem? Also, I'm on linux.

Comment: @Cobo it works on v. 9 as well (at least on my Mac)

Comment: @Cobo Also runs here on MMa 9 (Windows 8). Maybe the problem is on the data? Are you sure the data input is in the correct form?